# Switching Keras backend Tensorflow to GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu

I use Keras-Tensorflow combo installed with CPU option (it was said to be more robust), but now I'd like to try it with GPU-version. Is there a convenient way to switch? Or shall I re-install fully Tensorflow? Is the GPU version reliable?

Comment: I've installed TF version for GPU and doesn't work. I've to wrtie any command line on my code for using GPU?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest reinstalling the GPU version of Tensorflow, although you can install both version of Tensorflow via [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). GPU version of Tensorflow supports CPU computation, you can switch to CPU easily:

```
with device('/cpu:0'):
    # your code here
```

I have been using GPU version of Tensorflow on my Tesla K80 for a few months, it works like a charm. Feel free to have a try!

Answer (score 2):

You would first have to uninstall tensorflow and after that install tensorflow-gpu. After that run your code and it would run on GPU provided you have installed gpu libraries such as CUDA and cuDNN.

Answer (score 1):

Once you installed the GPU version of Tensorflow, you don't have anything to do in Keras. As written in the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/), *"If you are running on the TensorFlow backend, your code will automatically run on GPU if any available GPU is detected."*

And if you want to check that the GPU is correctly detected, start your script with:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

The standard output should not show any error and print the name of the GPU. If so, you are ready to run Keras and Tensorflow in GPU mode.